# Using a sub query to get a value from another row using a current row value - 1

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to include a value from another row by using a sub query in PostgreSQL. The sub query will subtract 1 for the current rows vale to find the other. For instance, the "previous_leg_order" is calculated as 2 and then using that, the sub query looks up the previous record.

```
SELECT 
    call_logs.id,
    call_legs.leg_order - 1 as previous_leg_order,
    (SELECT call_legs.from_name FROM call_legs WHERE call_logs.id = call_legs.call_id AND call_legs.leg_order = 2) as previous_leg_from_name,
    call_logs.from_name,
    call_legs.from_name,    
    call_legs.leg_order,
    call_legs.result
FROM call_logs, call_legs
WHERE call_logs.id = call_legs.call_id  
AND call_legs.from_name = 'John Smith'
AND call_logs.from_name SIMILAR TO 'CS%'
 AND call_legs.result = 'Call connected'
 AND call_legs.start_time >= '02/20/2022 12:00 AM' AND call_legs.start_time <= '02/27/2022 12:00 AM'
```

Replacing the "call_legs.leg_order = 2" with "call_legs.leg_order = call_legs.leg_order - 1" or "call_legs.leg_order = previous_leg_order" retuns nothing or a "column "previous_leg_order" does not exist" error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for the function `lag() over`.
`lag(call_logs.from_name) over(order by call_legs.call_id )`. Lag also takes an argument to say how many lines previous it should take the value from and can by use with `partition by`.

> ```
> create table call_logs(
> id int,
> from_name varchar(50)
> );
> insert into call_logs values
> (1,'CS John Smith'),
> (2,'CS Bill Jones');
>
> create table call_legs (
> call_id int,
> leg_order int,
> from_name varchar(50),
> result varchar(50),
> start_time timestamp
> );
> insert into call_legs values
> (1,1,'John Smith','Call connected',TO_DATE('21/02/2022','DD/MM/YYYY')),
> (2,2,'John Smith','Call connected',TO_DATE('21/02/2022','DD/MM/YYYY'));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

2 rows affected

> ✓

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT 
>     call_logs.id,
>     call_legs.leg_order - 1 as previous_leg_order,
>     (SELECT call_legs.from_name FROM call_legs 
>     WHERE call_logs.id = call_legs.call_id 
>     AND call_legs.leg_order = 2) as previous_leg_from_name,
>     call_logs.from_name,
>     call_legs.from_name,    
>     call_legs.leg_order,
>     call_legs.result,
>     lag(call_logs.from_name) over(order by call_legs.call_id )
> FROM call_logs, call_legs
> WHERE call_logs.id = call_legs.call_id  
> AND call_legs.from_name = 'John Smith'
> AND call_logs.from_name SIMILAR TO 'CS%'
>  AND call_legs.result = 'Call connected'
>  AND call_legs.start_time >= '20/02/2022 12:00 AM' AND call_legs.start_time <= '27/02/2022 12:00 AM'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | previous_leg_order | previous_leg_from_name | from_name     | from_name  | leg_order | result         | lag          
> -: | -----------------: | :--------------------- | :------------ | :--------- | --------: | :------------- | :------------
>  1 |                  0 | null                   | CS John Smith | John Smith |         1 | Call connected | null         
>  2 |                  1 | John Smith             | CS Bill Jones | John Smith |         2 | Call connected | CS John Smith
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1b7cb448640c75668af052c1a5126227)*